# Extracting duplicate from array of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Hi i have an array of dicts that looks like this:

```
books = [
         {'Serial Number': '3333', 'size':'500', 'Book':'The Hobbit'},
         {'Serial Number': '2222', 'size':'100', 'Book':'Lord of the Rings'},
         {'Serial Number': '1111', 'size':'200', 'Book':'39 Steps'},
         {'Serial Number': '3333', 'size':'600', 'Book':'100 Dalmations'},
         {'Serial Number': '2222', 'size':'800', 'Book':'Woman in Black'},
         {'Serial Number': '6666', 'size':'1000', 'Book':'The Hunt for Red October'},
        ]
```

I need to create a separate array of dicts that looks like this based on duplicate serial numbers:

```
duplicates = [
    '3333', [{'Book':'The Hobbit'}, {'Book':'100 Dalmations'}],
    '2222', [{'Book':'Lord of the Rings'}, {'Book':'Woman in Black'}]
]
```

Is there an easy way to do this using a built in function, if not whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What if there are more than 1 duplicate?

Comment: Good question, I've revised my question to take this into consideration!

Comment: Your edit is not a valid python data structure.

Comment: Well spotted - fixed!

Comment: Still not quite valid

Comment: Nope. `duplicates` is a dictionary, it needs to have a mapping, not just a list as the second element.

Comment: Yeah, just saw that, Try now!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most pythonic way I can think about:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)

for d in books:
    res[d.pop('Serial Number')].append(d)

print({k: v for k, v in res.items() if len(v) > 1})
```

Output:

```
{'2222': [{'Book': 'Lord of the Rings', 'size': '100'},
          {'Book': 'Woman in Black', 'size': '800'}],
 '3333': [{'Book': 'The Hobbit', 'size': '500'},
          {'Book': '100 Dalmations', 'size': '600'}]}
```

Comment: This seems to work well. However, how can I now get the "size" for each of the books in this new structure?

Comment: @user1513388 e.g for The Hobbit: `hobbit = [x for x in duplicates['2222'] if x['Book'] == 'The Hobbit'][0]`. Now you can get the size like this: `hobbit['size']`